# Why can't I see my test text on the front page of my original React web app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, debugging

As of now, my React app runs on `port 3000` via `npm start`.

I've decided that I want to use MySQL for the web app I'm building via `yarn add express mysql`.

I made `server.js` listen in on port 3001.

Whenever I run `nodemon server.js` and then hit refresh, I'm not seeing `test` on the front page of my React app (which would indicate that everything works fine).

I can see `test` if I type `localhost: 3001` in my browser but it's completely blank, meaning, I only see `test` and not the original front page of my web app.  It's a whole new different page.

Inside `package.json` file, I tried to include `"proxy":"http://localhost:3001"` at the bottom of the file as well as various other places, but it still doesn't work.

How do I make it so that I can see `test` on the original front page of my web app (`port 3000`) so I can conclude that everything's working fine and can proceed with integrating MySQL?

Here's my `server.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('test');
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("listening port 3001");
});
```

Comment: What are you seeing in the browser when you hit http://localhost:3000?

Comment: @HemadriDasari the login page of my web app without `test`.

Comment: `test` is in :3001

Comment: @Emeeus yeah I know, but I want it appear in 3000 so that everything's connected.

Comment: ok. On which port you want to see original front page?

Comment: @HemadriDasari I wanna see it on port 3000 along with `test`

Comment: you can't create two servers using the same port

Comment: @Emeeus ah ok, so I should try to integrate MySQL without the use of express is what you're trying to say?

Comment: ok. Use fetch/axios to make ajax call to http://localhost:3001 and get the response and display it in original front page

Comment: You could integrate both servers if you wish, when you need a url, write the correct port.

Comment: @HemadriDasari oh ok.  this wouldn't hinder my intentions of storing usernames/passwords using MySQL right?

Comment: To store username, password or any data into database irrespective of whether mysql, oracle any DB. You need either axios or react internal fetch to make an api call from front end(react component) to the backend(wr you catch those details and store it into the db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

If you don't need to build and try your app in production, meaning you only need to run both of them for development then just use a proxy as suggested in the comments. Run both servers and make requests to your Express API routes on the frontend. You can add a proxy like this in your client's (React part) `package.json` file.

```
"proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3001"
    }
}
```

Then, any request made for `/api/*` on the frontend goes through your Express server.

For starting both servers at the same time, you can use `concurrently`. First install it on the server side:

yarn add `concurrently`

After installing it you add something like this in your `scripts` part:

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js"
},
```

I misunderstood your intention at first, this is why I gave an answer like the below one.

---

This is normal behavior since you haven't configured Express to serve your frontend properly.

First of all, for a React app you don't need any server at all. What you are using right now (on port 3000) is for developing purposes. So, after completing your app you should build it and configure Express to serve it statically.

First, build it:

```
yarn build
```

After this step, you will have static files in your client's `build` directory.

Now, your Express config should be something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('test');
});

app.use( express.static( "client/build" ) );
app.get( "*", ( req, res ) =>
    res.sendFile( path.resolve( __dirname, "client", "build", "index.html" ) ) );

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("listening port 3001");
});
```

Notice the route change for Express. I changed `/` with `/test`. So, when you hit `/test` you will see what your Express route serves. Other than this route you should see your React app.

Also, don't forget to change those if your setup is different:

```
client/build
```

and

```
path.resolve( __dirname, "client", "build", "index.html" )
```

This means Express searches a `client` directory and you React app resides there.

PS: You will only start the Express server, there will be no more server for React since you don't need it to serve with Express.

Also, related part can be enhanced like this:

```
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ) {
  app.use( express.static( "client/build" ) );

  app.get( "*", ( req, res ) =>
    res.sendFile( path.resolve( __dirname, "client", "build", "index.html" ) )     );
}
```

So, at runtime you can pass an environment variable and Express hits this route only in production.

Comment: ah ok.  I see what you're saying.  My intentions with this whole thing is store username/passwords and eventually associate items selected (buttons clicked) to the corresponding username via MySQL.  I'm already storing username and passwords using Firebase but I wanted to switch to MySQL to easier associate items selected (buttons clicked) to the corresponding username via MySQL.

Comment: So, if you need a server like Express this is the way you will go. Development and production configuration are a little bit different as you can see.